# NSFetchedResultsController running after performing push on UINavigationController

Tags: performance, background, uinavigationcontroller, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I am using an `NSFetchedResultsController` with my tableview inside of a `UINavigationControler`. When an item is tapped on the tableview I perform a 'push' and pass a specific entity in the `prepareForSegue` in order to show more detailed data about that record.

In the detail view controller the model can be edited. There appears to be a lot of lag when I change the model. And I noticed that the `tableView:cellforRowAtIndexPath:` on the previous view controller is being called.

I've tried using `performSelectorInBackground:` but doesn't seem to help much.

Once push a view controller, isn't the view controller below not supposed to run? Has anyone been able to overcome this lag issue?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually ran into this tonight and solved it by adding a new bool property on my view controller to store when my VC is visible.

```
@property (nonatomic, assign, getter = isVisble) BOOL visible;
```

Then I check at the top of FRC delegate methods if the view is visible or not.

```
- (void)controllerWillChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller {
    if (! self.isVisble) {
        return;
    }

    [tableView beginUpdates];
}
```

This seems to help stuttering and performance when the VC with the FRC has been pushed behind other VCs.